# Why does the image refresh so quickly in HTML5 regardless of what I put for timeout?

Tags: html

no  matter what value I will it will always refresh as fast as it can.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var ctx, canvas;



        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback) {
              window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/1 );
            };
      })();

            window.onload = function(){
                canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                //sciana
                drawLine();

            }
            function drawLine(){
            var bok = 400, xw = canvas.width/2, yw = 10, odstep = 10;
            var tX = 10/Math.sqrt(3);
                ctx.save();
                for(var i = xw; i >= xw - bok/2; i-=tX){
                    var r = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var g = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var b = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());   
                    ctx.translate(10/Math.sqrt(3), 10);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    ctx.arc(xw, 0, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.closePath();

                }   
                ctx.restore(); 
                ctx.save();
                    for(var i = xw; i >= xw - bok/2; i-=10/Math.sqrt(3)){
                    var r = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var g = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var b = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());   
                    ctx.translate(-10/Math.sqrt(3), 10);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    ctx.arc(xw, 0, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.closePath();
                }   
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.save();
                xw = xw - bok/2 ;
                yw = bok*Math.sqrt(3)/2;
                for(var i = xw; i <= xw + bok; i+=10){
                    var r = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var g = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var b = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());   
                    ctx.translate(10,0);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    ctx.arc(xw, yw, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
                ctx.restore();
                requestAnimFrame(drawLine);             
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:#D0D0D0">
            Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje elementu Canvas.
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to try reducing your code to the shortest snippet that still reproduces your issue. You'll save us a lot of time and in doing so you'll probably solve the problem yourself.

Comment: If you don't understand it by only reading the description you won't help, go away and don't write if you are not going to help.

Comment: That's not how this site works. If you don't want our feedback, the onus is on *you* to *not post here*. You do not get a say in who responds to your questions. You've posted a question containing a wall of code that *nobody* wants to read through. I'm suggesting that you'll get better answers if you post *good* questions containing a reasonable amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because expressions work like this:

```
return true || false || function()  {
// do something
};
```

The function will never get executed because JavaScript goes from left to right until it finds something true and then aborts ..

Comment: return (/* all the requestFrame etc. here */) && function (callback) {}

Comment: should work. but it would help if you could minimize your code to the problem only ..